# Proving a set is finite union of open intervals in $\Bbb R$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $E \subset R$ be a measurable set with a finite perimeter.

$$ P(E) = \sup \left\{ \int_{E}^{}  \varphi' (x) ~ dx  ~\middle|~ \varphi \in C_{c}^{1}(\Bbb R), ~ \| \varphi \|_{\infty} \leq 1        \right\} <  \infty. $$

Show that, up to a set of zero Lebesgue measures, $E$ is a finite union of open intervals.

I came across the above problem in a calculus of variation book and I do not know how to proceed with the proof. However, the book suggested trying the L**ebesgue density points theorem**. I can not connect this question with the Lebesgue density points theorem. Any help is appreciated a lot.

Comment: As an example, what happens if there is an infinite, increasing sequence $x_1 < y_1 < x_2 < y_2 < \ldots$ of real numbers such that every $x_i$ has density $1$ in $E$ and every $y_i$ has density $0$ in $E$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring.  Do we assume that $E$ is open in the first place?

Comment: No, not at all.  The only assumptions are that $E$ is measurable and $P(E)$ is finite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $d : \mathbb{R} \to [0,1]$ denote the density of a given point inside $E$, and let $E_z =  d^{-1}(z)$. *Note that by Lebesgue's density theorem, $d$ is defined on almost all of $\mathbb{R}$, so if you want, just define $d(x)=1/2$ anytime the density doesn't exist, and it won't impact the following argument.*

Define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $E_1 \subset \mathbb{R}\setminus E_0$ by $x\sim y$ if and only if $x,y$ lie in the same connected component of $\mathbb{R}\setminus E_0$.  Let $R$ denote a set of unique representatives for the partition corresponding to $\sim$ (i.e. $R$ is the image of a choice function on the partition)

We will prove that $$\begin{equation}\tag{$*$} P(E) < \infty \implies |R|<\infty,\end{equation}$$ but it might be nice to first see how $|R| < \infty$ gives us the intended conclusion.  Therefore, suppose we've already shown $R$ is finite.

One of the implications of Lebesgue's density theorem is that the symmetric difference $E \Delta E_1$ has measure zero, so it suffices to show that $E_1$ is a finite union of open intervals, up to a set of measure zero.

To approximate $E_1$, we use $R$: For any $x\in R$, let $C_x$ denote the component in $\mathbb{R}\setminus E_0$ containing $x$. Then by definition, $$E_1 \subset \bigcup_{x\in R} C_x \subset \mathbb{R}\setminus E_0$$
so $$E_1 \Delta \bigcup_{x\in R} C_x = \left(\bigcup_{x\in R}C_x\right)\setminus E_1 \subset \mathbb{R}\setminus (E_0\cup E_1)$$
which has measure zero by Lebegue's density theorem, so $E_1 \Delta \bigcup_{x\in R} C_x$ has measure zero.

Finally, $\bigcup_{x\in R} C_x$ is a finite union of intervals, from which we can throw away the finitely many boundary points to see it is equal to a finite union of open intervals, up to a set of measure zero.

---

With that taken care of, we only need to show $(*)$.  To this end, suppose $R$ is infinite.

Then $R$ contains either a decreasing sequence or an increasing sequence.  Without loss of generality, by replacing $E$ with $-E$, we may assume $R$ contains an increasing sequence $x_1 < x_2 < x_3 < \ldots$

Further, since $x_i < x_{i+1}$ don't lie in the same component of $\mathbb{R}\setminus E_0$, there is some $y_i \in E_0$ such that $x_i < y_i < x_{i+1}$.

Therefore, we have an infinite increasing sequence of real numbers $$x_1 < y_1 < x_2 < y_2 < \ldots$$
such that each $x_i$ has density $1$ in $E$ and each $y_i$ has density $0$ in $E$.

To finish, I'll leave you with a question:

> Define $y_0 = x_1-1$.  For each $i$, can you find a $\varphi_i \in C^1_c(\mathbb{R})$ supported on $\left[\tfrac12(y_{i-1}+x_i), \tfrac12(y_i+x_{i+1})\right]$ such that $\|\varphi\|_\infty =1$ and $\int_E \varphi'(x)\,dx \geq 1/2$?